# How to deal with SQLite migrations in React-Native using TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, sqlite, react-native, typeorm, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am writing a React-Native app which heavily relies on local storage, and have chosen [TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm)to handle this.

I am now entering a phase where my project is live, and I want to add new functionalities that require an adjustment to my datamodel. To start, I have used the react-native-example project. I have built my datamodel on this and would now like to implement a migration into it.

There seems to be no definitive manual/guide on how to perform migrations on React-Native.
Since I don't have access to the databases of my users, I can't run the migrations manually. So far, I found out that there is a 'migrationsRun' option in the connection settings which can be set to true, forcing migrations to be executed at every launch of the app, if needed.

Question then is: How should the actual migrations be created, what should they look like (plain sql queries?), and where should I put them?

Any guidance on migrations in a react-native app would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and managed to get migrations running in a react native context by providing the following properties as the `createConnection` options:

- synchronize: `false`
- migrationsRun: `true`
- migrations: [`migrationFile`]

Where the `migrationFile` is directly imported (rather than using a file path regex) and looks like the below (with inline SQL statements):

```
import { MigrationInterface } from 'typeorm'

module.exports = class PostRefactoring1579804977343 implements MigrationInterface {
  async up(queryRunner) {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "workouts" ADD COLUMN "questionSetId" text`)
  }

  async down(queryRunner) {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "workouts" DROP COLUMN "questionSetId"`)
  }
}
```

The above migration file looks slightly different to the examples you will see on https://typeorm.io/#/migrations as I'm not using TypeScript plus I had to add `module.exports` as I'm importing the file directly

The major (almost) undocumented discovery for seemingly getting this to work in react-native is the magical `migrationsRun` property which I discovered here [reactnativeconnectionoptions](http://typeorm.delightful.studio/interfaces/_driver_react_native_reactnativeconnectionoptions_.reactnativeconnectionoptions.html#migrations)

You can add more migration files over time to the `migrations` array config as needed and be sure to give them a unique class name with appropriate timestamp. It seems to keep an on device log of which migrations have run - to stop them running multiple times on the same device

Note: the requirement to have `synchronize: false` means that you will need to do an initial synchronize of your schemas upon first install of the app (which I initially set using a flag in AsyncStorage to indicate first app install)

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH**

The above approach means we are then manually maintaining our schema setup after the initial user installation. Whereas I quite like the idea of having the schema managed automatically if possible - with migrations used just to manipulate the data.

So an alternative way to achieve this is to call the `synchronize` and `runMigrations` methods directly when initialising the connection. In this instance you will need to check that particular tables exist within your migration scripts as they will run first, and so the tables they need to update may not yet exist if it's the first time the user opens the app after installation

Connection options:

```
export const initialiseDataStoreService = async () => {
  const connection = await createConnection({
    type: 'react-native',
    database: 'main.sqlite',
    location: 'default',
    logging: [ 'error', 'schema'],
    entities: [
      CoreData,
      Workouts,
    ],
    migrations: [PostRefactoring1579804977343],
  })

  await connection.runMigrations()
  await connection.synchronize()

  return connection
}
```

Updated migration script:

```
import { MigrationInterface, TableColumn } from 'typeorm'

module.exports = class PostRefactoring1579804977343 implements MigrationInterface {
  async up(queryRunner) {
    const hasWorkoutsTable = await queryRunner.hasTable('workouts')
    if (hasWorkoutsTable) {
      await queryRunner.addColumn(
        'workouts',
        new TableColumn({
          name: 'questionSetId',
          type: 'text',
          // we make the new field nullable in order to enable the update
          // for existing data (schema sync will later update this column to be non
          // nullable)
          isNullable: true,
        }),
      )
      await queryRunner.query(
        `UPDATE workouts SET questionSetId = "MIGRATION-PLACEHOLDER" WHERE questionSetId IS NULL`,
      )
    }
  }

  async down(queryRunner) {
    const hasWorkoutsTable = await queryRunner.hasTable('workouts')
    if (hasWorkoutsTable) {
      await queryRunner.dropColumn('workouts', 'questionSetId')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: This alternative method shown above made it feel a bit cleaner too when jumping through hoops related to updating content in existing tables with non nullable fields - which had me cursing why I still even found myself using SQL in the year 2020 but alas it seems to be the best option for local storage in React-Native at time of writing. I did try Realm but it seemed to have some major (and seemingly unpredictable) memory issues

Comment: also, using `AsyncStorage` to store if the app has been initially installed may be a flawed idea as I think `AsyncStorage` items get backed up to iCloud so if the user re installs the app via iCloud you may get stuck in a weird situation where the app thinks the initial schema sync has happened on a given device but really it has not. Storing device id specific keys could mitigate this to some extent

Comment: For the first approach, how come we need to do a synchronize the first time but not for any other migrations that come later

Comment: thanks for the answer, with what command are you generating migrations @Rusta ?